# php object to array

Tags: javascript, php, массивы

Этот вопрос мусолился не раз, но все же, вот с чем столкнулся...

---

**Вариант №1**

PHP:

```
<?php  
$fields = [];

$fields[0] = 0;
$fields[2] = 2;
$fields[1] = 1;

$fields = (array) $fields;

die(json_encode($fields));
```

JS console:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
__proto__: Object
```

---

**Вариант №2**

PHP:

```
<?php  
$fields = [];

$fields[0] = 0;
$fields[2] = 2;
$fields[1] = 1;

/// Дальше любые манипуляции с массивом
$fields = array_merge([],$fields);
///$fields = array_reverse($fields);$fields = array_reverse($fields);
///$fs = []; foreach( $fields AS $k=>$f ) $fs[$k] = $f; $fields = $fs;
///$fields = get_object_vars((object)$fields);

die(json_encode($fields));
```

JS console:

```
[0, 2, 1]
0: 0
1: 2
2: 1
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

---

> 1 вариант: this.fields.forEach ругается
>   2 вариант: порядок нарушается

Вижу только такой выход:

```
<?php
$fields = [];

$fields[0] = 0;
$fields[1] = NULL;
$fields[2] = 2;
$fields[1] = 1;

die(json_encode($fields));
```

Я одну часть массива формирую, потом в него добавляю
Предположил, прописывание индексов создаст порядок

Почему так происходит?
Какие еще варианты есть, что бы сделать массив не теряя последовательности?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать строковые литералы в качестве ключей массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложил бы передавать из php объект вместо массива.
php:

```
$arr = [
  '0' => 0,
  '2' => 2,
  '1' => 1,
];

echo json_encode($arr); // {"0":0,"2":2,"1":1}
```

Вслед за @ЕгорБанин предложу `for in` для итерации свойств объекта. Но это для es6.
В es5 придется немного "поплясать с бубном".

js:

```
var arr = JSON.parse('{"0":0,"2":2,"1":1}');
// es6
for (var item in arr) {
  console.log(item);
}

// es5
for (var idx = 0; idx < Object.keys(arr).length; idx++) {
  console.log(arr[idx]);
}

// 0
// 1 
// 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Так происходит потому, что при сериализации массива в PHP функцией `json_encode` можно получить массив или объект в зависимости от того, был ли массив **простым списком**. Важно понимать, что значения в списке **отсортированы** и при обращении ко второму элементу списка вы получите второй элемент, а не элемент с индексом 2. Могучие массивы php тут требуют деликатного обращения. Если вам нужен список, то преобразуйте массив в список перед сериализацией (например с помощью функции `array_values`), но будьте внимательны позиция элемента в списке и его ключ не одно и то же.

Для понимания происходящего выполните (например в консоли `php -a`) такой код:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[2] = 'два';
$arr[1] = 'один';
$arr[0] = 'ноль';

$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    echo "итерация $i - ключ $k\n";
    ++$i;
}
```

Кстати, в js вы можете итерировать объекты с помощью [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).